# Click en un elemento <a> href = javascript mediante drivers

Tags: javascript, eclipse, selenium

Soy bastante nuevo en esto del selenium y se me ha planteado la siguiente incógnita. Quiero poder añadir un producto a una cesta de venta dentro de una página. Para realizar dicha tarea, he de poder hacer click en un enlace en concreto pero este se presenta de tal forma:

[image: Enlace para añadir elemento al carrito de la compra]

Mi código para acceder a dicho enlace en concreto consiste en lo siguiente(el driver está configurado para chrome y accede de forma correcta a la página. El xpath es el correcto como se muestra en amarillo en la imagen superior):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Podría alguien echarme una mano para comprender el por qué no funciona?

Gracias

Comment: Prueba con distintos localizadores, tu xpath me da la sensacion que esta mal declarado.  //div[@class='btnSection']

Comment: Ya lo he resuelto. Como decía Alex tenía mal declarado el path. Gracias por contestar.